# Join a table only if result set > 0

Tags: sql, join

I have a table A joined with a table B which give me a result set.
I want to join a table C to the previous ones in order to restrict the result set. But in case there is no result with this join, I would like to have the same result set than before (without taking care of C).

Can you think of way to do that in SQL ?

Comment: Try googling for `outer join`.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, ...?

Comment: The problem with an OUTER JOIN is that I get all the results all the time, and the goal to join this new table is to restrict the result set.

Comment: Should work on AS/400 and DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with regular SQL since it involves logic.

Your best bet is to make a small script, e.g. (in pseudo code)

```
select * into #tmp from x inner join y inner join z where blabla;
if (exists (select * from #tmp))
BEGIN
  select * from #tmp
END
else
BEGIN
   select * from x inner join y where blabla;
END
```

Edit:

But if I were you, I would just always join with C using a LEFT JOIN, so you can see if the result was in one or the other result set...

e.g.

```
select x.*, y.*, case when z.id is null then 0 else 1 end from x inner join y left join z on blabla where blabla;
```

But that of course assumes you are able to alter the code path that reads the result.

Comment: Why not simply use an outer join?

Comment: As I read the question, that is not what he wants to do... He wants to have two distinctly different data sets depending on the value of one of them

Comment: Cine you're right, that is exactly what I am trying to do, but my goal is to stay at the SQL level. Don't you think it is possible with CASE or some other keyword ?

Comment: My pseudo code is SQL (I used sql server syntax), you should be able to make something similar in db2

Comment: cudos to you for being able to decipher what the OP was after!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.ID = TableB.TableAID
LEFT JOIN TableC
    ON TableC.ID = TableB.TableCID
```

This will return all rows from Tables A & B but only the rows from TableC where the ON criteria match.

Otherwise conditional joins don't really apply in standard SQL. If you are using SQL Server you can perform some stored procedure logic to check the results from TableC and if there are none then only get data from Table A & B. But this approach with be provider specific

Comment: The problem with this is that I will still have all the results from the joined A and B tables.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in the LEFT/OUTER JOIN methods. If you do it you could get some results that are in A and B but not in C. If I understand well the porpouse is join AB with C, I mean the result when crossing with C must include the three restrictions. So the @Cine solution is the apropiate to this case.